# Triggering Jenkins using github generic web hook

Tags: java, regex, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I am pretty new to Jenkins and this is my first attempt of configuring pipeline jobs. 
I have created a pipeline job in jenkins. Now I have to trigger this job when ever there is a commit to master branch of my github repository. While doing this, I am totally stuck with couple of issues. Any help will be highly appreciated.

<strike>a) First issue is while sending trigger from github.
Our jenkins uses a secured connection(https). As suggested in some other threads, I tried adding the "userName:password" before the host name.
So the url in github looks like</strike>

```
https://username:password@jenkins.ourorg.com/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke
```

My password contains '@' so i replaced it with '%40'.
I got the following error

> We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't resolve host name

b) Since I couldn't proceed with the github webhook, i thought of mocking it with  a java program.

```
String type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(new FileInputStream(new File("payload.json")));
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(tokener);
System.out.println(jsonObject);  


//getMockCertificate() returns an empty array of X509Certificate
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(getMockCertificate().getSocketFactory());
URL url = new URL("https://jenkins.ourorg.com/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke");

String userCredentials = "userName:password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpsCon.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);


httpsCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpsCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpsCon.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", type );
httpsCon.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf(jsonObject.toString().length()));

OutputStream os = httpsCon.getOutputStream();
os.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());

System.out.println(httpsCon.getResponseCode());
String line;
int a;

while((a = httpsCon.getInputStream().read()) != -1){
    System.out.print((char)a);
}
```

Having the '**Authorization**' header helped me to bypass the secured connection issue. **payload.json** is a JSON file I created with the content copied from github webhook Recent Deliveries. Without any filters the job is getting triggered. 
Now I need to filter with the '**ref**' tag in payload.json

[image]

so that the job triggers only for commits to 'master' branch.

For this purpose I added following configs under the BuildTriggers/Generic Webhook Trigger.

[image]

[image]

Now the job is not getting triggered at all. If i use a regular expression to pass any value, it works.

I also check the regular expression & the value against an online web page and it seems to be correct.

[image]

Since this is an enterprise jenkins, I do not have permission to see the main logs of jenkins to see what is getting delivered while I make a request.

> ************************UPDATE*************************

Issue (a) is resolved now. Same URL did the trick. Only difference is in the way i set the URL. initially I typed @ in the password and github automatically converted it to %40. this time i typed %40 instead of @. it worked. Issue(b) is still pending to be resolved, even though the git hub is capable of triggering the request. I believe it has something to do with the **regular expression**

Comment: Is jenkins under nat?

Comment: i am sorry, what is 'nat'?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation Jenkins address should be available from web, not only from your PC

Comment: No, its not. i couldn't access it from my mobile browser.

Comment: Got it resolved. There was a space after the 'reference' variable name, which created the issue.